# Django rest_framework datetime_format with milliseconds

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, timestamp

Django REST_FRAMEWORK has a setting for the date format, e.g for timestamp in seconds:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s',
}
```

so my API output is for instance:

```
{"creation_date":"1610700530"}
```

How would I tell it to output a timestamp in milliseconds? E.g.:

```
{"creation_date":"1610700530000"}
```

Comment: yes you are right, thank you. the last answer is an answer to my question - i can use `'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s000'`

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer, the option would be:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': '%s%03d',
}
```